# Convert Dates to DATEPARSE

Tags: sql, date, tableau-desktop

In Tableau the DATEPARSE format option works well when the raw data shows 202201 ,202202 2022 ,202203. The formula I normally use is DATEPARSE('yyyyMM',str(DATE)) which then I get Jan, 2022, Feb 2022 and March 2022. etc. (by the way, you must extract before using this option, I know, I know)

I have three (3) tables and I'm trying to connect each of the tables by "relationships", when creating a relationships calculation the DATEPARSE doesn't work. Is there any other way to convert these dates to a regular DATE? or how would I code this in SQL--
My 3-tables are "custom SQL" I could formulate this issue there correct?

Picture where I'm trying to create relationships --the DATEPARSE doesn't even show as an option--Is there any other way? Or my only solution is to create something in SQL

Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpdm4.png)

Answer (score 0):

For your DATEPARSE problem,
I suggest you use two field on joining with relationship.

The two joining field as below:

Year([DATE1]) = Year([DATE2])

Month([DATE1]) = Month([DATE2])

The result should be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAMzb.png)

You can edit the relationship joining by clicking "Edit Relationship Calculation"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback --I was able to solve the problem--My problem was that the Year and months are STR values